# how to map this route from mvc controller to a web api controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

We have a mvc project and we would like to move to a web api. The mvc project doesn't have any UI,so it was a mistake to use mvc controller other than a web api controller.

However, our customers access the mvc controller via url such as:

```
https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/indexes/unit/docs/search   (both httppost)
https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/indexes/unit/docs/post   (both httppost)
https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/indexes/unit/docs/get
```

the part unit/docs is actually dynamic (something we send to a database to do some query).

If we move this controller to web api, how can we handle the route as we need to be backward compatible?

Answer (score 0):

in your WebApi controller, do the following:

```
[route("{controller}")]
public IndexesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("{unit}/{docs}/{search}")]//or whatever those variables should be
    public async Task<IactionResult> Search(string unit, string docs, string search) 
    {
        //Do your stuff
        var result = _logic.DoStuff();
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

There's no reason to move away from MVC controller though. Just always return a JsonResult() and it'll behave exactly like a WebApi from the caller's perspective.

Comment: hi, tried this, but HttpPost constructor doesn't take a parameter? I want to move to web api as we want to return a HttpStatusCode 400 with our own message. Seems impossible with mvc controller

Comment: You can also try [HttpPost] followed by [Route("route/here")]